# Implicit parameter resolution - setting the precedence

Tags: scala, implicit

I am trying to create a typeclass `Default` that supplies the default value for a given type. Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
trait Default[A] {
  def value: A
}

object Default {
  def withValue[A](a: A) = new Default[A] {
    def value = a
  }

  def default[A : Default]: A = implicitly[Default[A]].value

  implicit val forBoolean = withValue(false)

  implicit def forNumeric[A : Numeric] = 
    withValue(implicitly[Numeric[A]].zero)

  implicit val forChar = withValue(' ')

  implicit val forString = withValue("")

  implicit def forOption[A] = withValue(None : Option[A])

  implicit def forAnyRef[A >: Null] = withValue(null : A)
}

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

case class Point(x: Double, y: Double)

object Point {
  implicit val pointDefault = Default withValue Point(0.0, 0.0)
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import Default.default
    println(default[Int])
    println(default[BigDecimal])
    println(default[Option[String]])
    println(default[String])
    println(default[Person])
    println(default[Point])
  }
}
```

The above implementation behaves as expected, except for the cases of `BigInt` and `BigDecimal` (and other user defined types that are instances of `Numeric`) where it gives `null` instead of zero. What should I do so that `forNumeric` takes precedence over `forAnyRef` and I get the behavior I expect?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `forAnyRef` implicit is chosen because it is *more specific* than `forNumeric` according to §6.26.3 “Overloading Resolution” of the Scala reference. There is a way to reduce its priority by moving it to a trait that `Default` extends, like this:

```
trait LowerPriorityImplicits extends LowestPriorityImplicits {
  this: Default.type =>

  implicit def forAnyRef[A >: Null] = withValue(null: A)

}

object Default extends LowerPriorityImplicits {
  // as before, without forAnyRef
}
```

But that's only part of the trick, because now both `forAnyRef` and `forNumeric` are as specific as each other, and you'll get an ambiguous-implicit error. Why is that? Well, `forAnyRef` gets an extra specificity point because it has a non-trivial constraint on `A`: `A >: Null`. What you can do then, to add a nontrivial constraint to `forNumeric`, is to double it in `Default`:

```
implicit def forNumericVal[A <: AnyVal: Numeric] = withValue(implicitly[Numeric[A]].zero)

implicit def forNumericRef[A <: AnyRef: Numeric] = withValue(implicitly[Numeric[A]].zero)
```

Now, this additional constraint makes `forNumericVal` and `forNumericRef` more specific that `forAnyRef` for types where a `Numeric` is available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Jean. Tweaking your solution I came up with another solution that avoids this little code duplication. I am posting it below for the benefit of readers.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another way to solve the problem, doesn't require any code duplication:

```
trait Default[A] {
  def value: A
}

object Default extends LowPriorityImplicits {
  def withValue[A](a: A) = new Default[A] {
    def value = a
  }

  def default[A : Default]: A = implicitly[Default[A]].value

  implicit val forBoolean = withValue(false)

  implicit def forNumeric[A : Numeric] = 
    withValue(implicitly[Numeric[A]].zero)

  implicit val forChar = withValue(' ')

  implicit val forString = withValue("")

  implicit def forOption[A] = withValue(None : Option[A])
}

trait LowPriorityImplicits { this: Default.type =>
  implicit def forAnyRef[A](implicit ev: Null <:< A) = withValue(null : A)
}

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

case class Point(x: Double, y: Double)

object Point {
  implicit val pointDefault = Default withValue Point(0.0, 0.0)
}

object Main {
  import Default.default

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(default[Int])
    println(default[BigDecimal])
    println(default[Option[String]])
    println(default[String])
    println(default[Person])
    println(default[Point])
  }
}
```