# Scala implicit type class dependency injection

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, akka, typeclass

I'd like some help sorting out this scenario. I have an Akka actor where I want to inject a dependency, in this case RemoteFetcher, which I would also like mock in my tests. Like so:

main/src/scala/**mypackage/Services.scala**

```
package mypackage
import RemoteFetcherFileSystem._

trait RemoteFetcher {
  def fetch( path:String ): Future[Stream[String]]
}

class MyRemoteResourceActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  def fetchRemote( path:String ) = implicitly[RemoteFetcher].fetch( path )
  def receive = {
     case FetchRemoteResource( path ) => fetchRemote( path ).map( _.foreach( sender ! _ ) )
  }
}
```

For this to work I have an implicit object that I import into the file above. Would look something like this:

```
implicit object RemoteFetcherFileSystem extends RemoteFetcher {
   def fetchRemote( path:String ) = Future[Stream[String]] { ... reading from file system ... }
}
```

Now in my tests I have TestActor from the akka-testkit. Here I want to instead import my mock dependency:

```
implicit object RemoteFetcherMock extends RemoteFetcher {
   def fetchRemote( path:String ) = Future[Stream[String]] { ... mock implementation ... }
}
```

My problem is that to compile Services.scala I need to import the implicit object. But how do I go about to shadow/override this in my test-files. The reason I'm not using implicit arguments is that I want to avoid having to modify all my actors constructor arguments.

I when looking around and reading up on the type class dependency injection pattern and I get it to work according to the tutorials, but I don't get it to work when I want to test and override like in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do it with implicits, but typically one could inject instead like so:

```
trait RemoteFetcherComponent {
  def remoteFetcher: RemoteFetcher
  trait RemoteFetcher {
    def fetch(path: String): Future[Stream[String]]
  }
}

trait RemoteFetcherFileSystemComponent extends RemoteFetcherComponent {
   val remoteFetcher = RemoteFetcherFileSystem
   object RemoteFetcherFileSystem extends RemoteFetcher {
     def fetch(path: String): Future[Stream[String]] = ???
   }
}

class MyRemoteResourceActor extends Actor with ActorLogging with RemoteFetcherFileSystemComponent {
  def fetchRemote(path: String) = remoteFetcher.fetch(path)
  def receive = {
     case FetchRemoteResource(path) => fetchRemote(path).map( _.foreach(sender ! _))
  }
}

val myRemoteResourceActor = new MyRemoteResourceActor()
```

And then a test value would be defined like so:

```
trait RemoteFetcherMockComponent extends RemoteFetcherComponent {
  def remoteFetcher = RemoteFetcherMock
  object RemoteFetcherMock extends RemoteFetcher {
    def fetch(path: String): Future[Stream[String]] = ???
  }
}

val myMockedResourceActor = new MyRemoteResourceActor with RemoteFetcherMockComponent {
  override val remoteFetcher = super[RemoteFetcherMockComponent].remoteFetcher
}
```

The reason you are having an issue with implicits is because the way you're using it is no different from simply using `def fetchRemote(path: String) = RemoteFetcherFileSystem.fetch(path)`. With the import, you've defined the implementation, rather than allowed it to be injected later.

Comment: So I guess you're suggesting to use the cake pattern here? Well it is worth a try. I got the impression in the tutorials I read that it was very verbose but it doesn't look too bad.

Comment: I added another answer with a way to do it with implicits. Maybe not exactly how you want it, or the best way, but it's definitely a starting point.

Comment: I think you meant to have the actor extend RemoteFetcherFileSystemComponent?

Comment: No, just the trait `RemoteFetcherComponent`. Then when you instantiate it you mixin `RemoteFetcherFileSystemComponent`, see the `val` in my example.

Comment: Hmmm... not sure this will work for my use case after all (at least as I defined it above). Since I don't instanciate the actor myself. Then again I could just pass constructor arguments. I'll have to take another look tomorrow, I guess I might just as well pass arguments to the constructor.

Comment: I updated my post with the modification you suggested, although I doubt it's the best way to go about this, the cake pattern here seems to be a bit of overengineering.

Comment: As for the RemoteFetcherComponent. Don't I have to convert the class into a trait then? class MyRemoteResourceActor -> trait MyRemoteResourceActor, as otherwise I have to implement the remoteFetcher and fetch methods in my class. Which I want to do in the component implementations, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You could also change the `implicitly` to an implicit parameter:

```
trait RemoteFetcher {
  def fetch(path: String): Future[Stream[String]]
}

object RemoteFetcher {
   implicit val fetcher = RemoteFetcherFileSystem
}

class MyRemoteResourceActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  def fetchRemote(path: String)(implicit remoteFetcher: RemoteFetcher) = remoteFetcher.fetch(path)
  def receive = {
     case FetchRemoteResource(path) => fetchRemote(path).map( _.foreach(sender ! _))
  }
}
```

Then you could override the implicit that is resolved in the companion object of `RemoteFetcher` by simply importing `RemoteFetcherMock`.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623055/scala-implicit-parameter-resolution-precedence) for more information about implicit parameter resolution precedence rules.

Comment: I tried that. But for some reason it did not really work out for me as I got implicit ambiguity collisions (maybe it was the REPL playing tricks on me). I guess that is an alternative as well. I think I will go with the cake pattern in the end.