# Creating a more specific implicit using a structural type with Scala

Tags: scala, types, typeclass, implicit-conversion, structural-typing

As far as I know there is no shared trait in the collections library that defines the `map` method (most likely because there are different signatures for `map`).

I have an observable value (think of a property in a ui system) that has a change event. The observable values can be mapped using a `map` method.

When we are however working with a type that already has a `map` method, we should be able to use the built-in method of `map`.

So instead of:

```
prop map { x => 
  x map { actualX =>
   //do something
  }
}
```

I want to use it like this:

```
prop map { actualX =>
  //do something
}
```

I have a simplified test case. First the different parts I am using:

```
// leaving out the observable part
trait ObservableValue[T] {
  def value: T
}

trait LowerPriorityImplicits {
  // default implementation that adds a regular map method
  implicit class RichObservableValue1[A](o: ObservableValue[A]) {
    def map[B](f: A => B): ObservableValue[B] = new ObservableValue[B] {
      def value = f(o.value)
    }
  }
}

object ObservableValue extends LowerPriorityImplicits {

  // describe a type that has a map method
  type HasMapMethod[A, Container[X]] = {
    def map[B](f: A => B): Container[B]
  }

  // complex implementation that uses the builtin map if present
  implicit class RichObservableValue2[A, Container[Z] <: HasMapMethod[Z, Container]](
      o: ObservableValue[Container[A]]) {

    def map[B](f: A => B): ObservableValue[Container[B]] = 
      new ObservableValue[Container[B]] {
        def value = o.value.map(f)
      }
  }
}
```

If there is something (or maybe a lot) wrong with the above code let me know. I want to use it like this:

```
class TestCase extends ObservableValue[Option[Int]] {
  def value = None
}

val x = new TestCase

x map { value =>
  // this fails because the compiler finds the lower priority implicit
  (value: Int).toString
}

// the method itself works fine
ObservableValue.RichObservableValue2(x) map { value =>
  (value: Int).toString
}
```

If I change `Container[B]` into `Any` it will find the `RichObservableValue2` implicit conversion.

My knowledge about how types are used to select implicits is limited.

I tried to find the answer in the following locations, but the subject is a bit overwhelming:

- [Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits)
- [How can I chain implicits in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332801/how-can-i-chain-implicits-in-scala)
- [Scala: Implicit parameter resolution precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623055/scala-implicit-parameter-resolution-precedence)
- http://eed3si9n.com/revisiting-implicits-without-import-tax
- Section 6.26.3 "Overloading Resolution" in the ScalaReference.pdf

Is there anyway to solve this challenge?

### Edit

I know about the `FilterMonadic` trait for collections. I am looking for a solution that recognizes the `map` method as defined in the `Option` class.

### Edit 2

It seems the `FilterMonadic` variant is not working either. I added `RichObservableValue3` to the `RichObservableValue` object.

```
implicit class RichObservableValue3[A, C[Z] <: FilterMonadic[Z, C[Z]]](o: ObservableValue[C[A]]) {

  def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[C[A], B, That]): ObservableValue[That] = new ObservableValue[That] {
    def value = o.value.map(f)

    val change = o.change map (_ map f)
  }
}
```

And again that implicit conversion is not chosen although a `List[Int]` is a valid argument. I must be missing some rule that is used when selecting implicits.

Comment: After an inexcusably brief glance at your question, I suggest you contemplate "Deprecating the Observer Pattern" by Maier and Odersky: http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~imaier/pub/DeprecatingObserversTR2010.pdf

Comment: I'm a little confused by "As far as I know there is no shared trait in the collections library that defines the `map` method (most likely because there are different signatures for map)." [`Traversable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Traversable), the base trait of every collection, defines `map`.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant Option as a collection as well. I should have probably called it differently. `FilterMonadic` is available for most collections, but it would be nice to have a more generic test on an appropriate map method. I will probably add a separate method for `FilterMonadic`, but this is more to catch `Option` like types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the part that I was missing. In order for the implicit to match I had to add the following type parameter:

```
T[Dummy <: Container[_]] <: ObservableValue[Dummy]
```

The resulting object:

```
object ObservableValue {

  implicit class Mappable[A](o: ObservableValue[A]) {

    def map[B](f: A => B): ObservableValue[B] = new ObservableValue[B] {
      def value = f(o.value)
    }
  }

  // FMC = FilterMonadicContainer
  // D = Dummy
  implicit class FilterMonadicMappable[A, FMC[D] <: FilterMonadic[D, FMC[D]]](o: ObservableValue[FMC[A]]) {

    def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[FMC[A], B, That]): ObservableValue[That] = new ObservableValue[That] {
      def value = o.value.map(f)
    }
  }

  type HasMap[A, That[_]] = {
    def map[B](f: A => B): That[B]
  }

  // OVC = ObservableValueContainer
  // MC = MappableContainer
  // D = Dummy
  implicit class SimpleMappable[A, MC[D] <: HasMap[D, MC], OVC[D <: MC[_]] <: ObservableValue[D]](o: OVC[MC[A]]) {

    def map[B](f: A => B): ObservableValue[MC[B]] = new ObservableValue[MC[B]] {
      def value = o.value.map(f)
    }
  }

}
```